# How to determine enzyme inhibitor efficacy?

Tags: enzymes

At what percentage reduction or increase in Km and Vmax is an enzyme inhibitor regarded as effective?- is any percentage increase or reduction regarded as being a clinically useful level of inhibition, or would it have to be over a certain limit?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify your posts, have a look at the [help]. Do you want to know more about this site, please take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

If the inhibitor is a competitive inhibitor, to quantify inhibition the $K_m$  of the inhibitor ($K_I$) is determined.

$K_I$ is compared to the $K_m$ of the substrate.

Then, the degree of inhibition is a function the inhibitor and substrate concentrations.

$V_{max}$ is unaffected by a competitive inhibitor.

In the presence of an inhibitor the kinetics are modified such that the enzyme has an effect $K_m$ as:

$K_m(1 + [I]/K_I)$